# Keypress in Angular-UI

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am running into some problems using the keypress as follows-

```
<div ng-controller="GBNController">
...
<input id="search-field" type="text" placeholder="JSON Query" ng-model="queryText" ui-keypress="{enter: foo()}"/>
...
</div>
```

and my javascript has -

```
var AngApp = angular.module('gbn', ['ui']);
var GBNController = function($scope) {
    $scope.queryText = '';
    $scope.foo = function() {
        alert('test');
    }
};
```

Now this function foo is called only when the document is loaded and then after that, the `return` keypress event in the text field is never handled.

I am using the current [head](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/tree/1d831cdf891dcbe9c1c2e7d95cd5c17f2b97fe69) of the master branch.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this broken??

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? Are you sure you bootstrap the 'gbn' module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put foo() in quotes.

`<input ui-keypress="{enter: 'foo()'}">`

Comment: I have the same problem, but even with the single quotes it doesn't work. I have a script tag pointing to angular-ui.min.js, a link tag pointing to angular-ui.min.css, a controller called NavbarCtrl, a method registerOnNewsletter on NavbarCtrl and a ui-keypress="{'enter':'registerOnNewsletter($event)'}" attribute in a input tag. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you include the 'ui' module in your app?
`angular.module('myApp', ['ui'])`

Comment: it should be:
`angular.module('myApp', ['ui.utils'])`
or
`angular.module('myApp', ['ui.keypress'])`

Answer (score 2):

You could easily just roll your own keypress directive

[Here's a plunker to demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sIDLoR)

And the code:

```
app.directive('zKeypress', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      elem.bind('keypress', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(s) {
          s.$eval(attr.zKeypress);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" z-keypress="foo()"/>
```

Comment: ui-keypress makes it a lot of things easier though.  For example, `<input ui-keypress="{enter: 'submit($event)', escape: 'cancel()', 26: 'otherThing()'}">`

Comment: Yeah, true. The angular-ui library just seems so bloated though.

Comment: Right now you can clone it and just get the directives you want built into the `build/custom` folder. For example if you wanted a js file with just ui-keypress and ui-event: `git clone https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui; cd angular-ui; grunt build:keypress:event`.  We hope to put custom builds downloadable on the website soon.

Comment: thanks for this sample. I believe it's necessary to also unbind the event from the element when it gets destroyed, isn't it ?